# If a closed curve has no antipodal points it must be contained in some open hemisphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

Whilst doing an exercise, on bounds on total absolute curvature I encountered the following obstacle:

Let $ \mathit c$ be a closed curve, whose trace is contained in $\mathbb S^2$, if c has no antipodal points, does this imply, that c is contained in some open hemisphere?
Intuitively I would argue, that if $ \pmb P, Q$ are the points on the curve that are the furthest apart, one takes the great circle parallel to the line connecting the two points, and then the curve should be contained, in one of the open hemispheres whose equator is formed by this great circle. I'm not sure if the claim is even true, and if yes how to make it rigorous. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is there a unique great circle parallel to a line?

Comment: I think this is false. Take a latitude circle around the north pole (of radius $<1$) and a corresponding latitude circle around the south pole of slightly different radius; puncture and join the two circles with a narrow tube. ... I am somewhat curious what the original exercise might have been. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin you're right there does not exist an unique great circle, what I meant is to take the line connecting the points P and Q and then choosing a diameter parallel to it, and then a great circle, where this diameter is contained. But I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: @TedShifrin what do you mean by "puncturing" ( english is not my mother tongue)? The original exercise, is to first show, that total absolute curvature of a closed space curve is at least pi and then to sharpen it to 2*pi.

Comment: Ah I think I understand what you mean with punctured. Your counterexample makes sense to me thank you for your help @TedShifrin

Comment: @TedShifrin (Waves) I upticked your comment (after having the same idea :), but am not convinced it works after all: The tube crosses the antipode of the latitude with smaller absolute value.

Comment: Or the other one? But yeah, that's right. Grr.

Comment: Oh, so you’re doing Fenchel’s Theorem. Things not unlike what you’re thinking about show up when you try to explain what happens with total curvature precisely $2\pi$.